# Empty slide content using beamer, xelatex, tikzexternal, and custom frame title with images

Tags: beamer, xetex, tikz-external

it's taken me a bit to determine the root cause of this problem, but beamer slides generated using xelatex and tikzexternalize with a custom frame title containing images does not work.  the generated slides do not contain any of the frame content.

the file is processed using "xelatex --shell-escape *.tex"

i've added an image of what it should look like since there were a couple of comments about why i am using images in the frame title the way that i do.  please note, the title text is usually centered.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\newdimen\leftlogosize
\newdimen\rightlogosize
\def\leftlogo{Physics_Logo.png}
\def\rightlogo{SanJac_Logo.png}
\leftlogosize=1.2cm
\rightlogosize=1.2cm

\newcommand{\drawlogo}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[height=#2]{#1}}%
  \x
}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {
      \drawlogo{\leftlogo}{\leftlogosize}};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {
      \drawlogo{\rightlogo}{\rightlogosize}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    external/system call={%
    xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
    -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode
    -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzset{external/optimize=false}%
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,1) -- (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Note that your code does *not* compile on my machine. Rather, I get a lengthy error starting with "! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -halt-on-error -interacti
on=batchmode -jobname "stackexchange-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{stackex
change}\input{stackexchange}"' did NOT result in a usable output ". I am using `xelatex`, what are you using? However, despite the error the picture is showing up (if I ignore the error). (Most likely this just means the picture is not getting externalized.)

Comment: @marmot You used shell escape?

Comment: @cfr No, I did not. Just called the MWE `stackexchange.tex` and run `xelatex stackexchange`.

Comment: You need to disable externalisation for cases where images must be compiled twice, such as anything where you're using something like `overlay`. Why such a convoluted `\drawlogo` macro? There are better ways of including logos like this into Beamer, using Beamer's facilities.

Comment: @marmot Well, obviously externalisation is expected to fail in that case ;).

Comment: @cfr Good to know. Is that specific to `xelatex`? I remember that it did work with `pdflatex` w/o shell escape.

Comment: @marmot No. It applies to any engine.

Comment: @cfr I am surprised. I had some time-consuming beamer animations successfully externalized and don't recall ever having used shell escape.

Comment: @marmot Then you have configured your system in an extremely insecure way. This is certain possible, but definitely not default. Rather you than me. One way or another, shell escape is needed. If it is enabled by default, you don't need the option to the command. Otherwise you do. If it is enabled by default, compilation can run any command on your system every time. By default, you have to pass the option to enable this on a particular run. Enabling it by default is like carrying a loaded gun with the safety catch off - sooner or later, you'll shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @cfr Thanks a lot! I was not aware of this. OK, but since my naive attempt to compile the file failed, I hope that this security risk does not exist on my current (new) computer.

Comment: @jameszabel Using tikz to add logos to the frametitle looks unnecessarily complicate - especially as the left hand image cloaks the frametitle in your example. Can you please add a sketch how the result should look like? I bet the frametitle can be done without tikz.

Comment: @samcarter i uploaded a picture of what the slide should look like.  if you have any suggestions about alternate methods, i'll gladly  take a look.  the image placement i use was the method i found ages ago when i customized my presentations.

Comment: @jameszabel So the frametitle should not be printed at all?

Comment: @jameszabel Should the images be on all non-plain slides or just on the ones with a frametitle?

Comment: @samcarter the images should only be on frames with a frametitle.  the second answer below seems to do the trick, though i've found a new issue that i'll place in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround could be not not use tikz to add simple images to the top of the frame, which seems a bit of overkill.

The image you showed us can easily be reproduces with the following headline:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \vskip0.5em%
    \hspace*{0.5em}%
    \includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-a}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-b}%
    \hspace*{0.5em}%
}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    external/system call={%
    xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
    -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode
    -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzset{external/optimize=false}%
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,1) -- (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you would like to display the frametitle as well, I suggest the following frametitle definition instead:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by -4.2cm%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \vskip-0.4cm%
    \hspace*{0.5em}%
  \hspace*{-\beamer@leftmargin}%
  \raisebox{-0.5cm}{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-a}}%
    \hspace*{0.5em}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima,ht=1.2cm,dp=0cm]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \hspace*{0.5em}%
  \raisebox{-0.5cm}{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{example-image-b}}%
    \hspace*{0.5em}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]